# More elegant way to check if values are in a range (0 to max_x, 0 to max_y) with Python

Tags: python

I have a 2D grid of cell objects with various properties. I made a list of the co-ordinates adjacent cells to the cell at x, y:

```
neighbors=[[x+i,y+j] for i in (-1,0,1) for j in (-1,0,1) if i != 0 or j != 0]
```

Now I want to remove any cells from this list that are off the edge of the grid. I popped them out like this and it works fine:

```
for i in range(len(neighbors)-1,-1,-1):
    max_x=10
    max_y=12
    if neighbors[i][0]<0 or neighbors[i][1]<0 or neighbors[i][0]>=max_x or neighbors[i][1]>=max_y:
      neighbors.pop(i)
```

That conditional is ugly. Is there a more elegant way to check if the neighbors exist?

Comment: what are initial `x, y` ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest This looks like part of Conway's Life, so presumably they'll be the coordinates of the current cell in the main update loop, and can vary from 0 to width and height.

Comment: It's not conways but rather an ant simulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same suggestion to use list comprehensions, but using `in range()` instead:

```py
max_x = 10
max_y = 12
neighbors = [[x, y] for x, y in neighbors if x in range(max_x) and y in range(max_y)]
```

Make sure values are always `int`/`float`, or else it'll be O(n)!

Comment: Why would it be O(n)?

Comment: b/c it'll actually iterate and try all of them: `'wrong type' in range(100_000_000)`

Comment: Nice suggestion, very clean! (though it'll be `O(n*(max_x + max_y))`, or clarify that estimate is for comparison only and nor for the whole listcomp and `n` is not a list size, as one might expect)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a list comprehension for that:

```py
max_x = 10
max_y = 12
neighbors = [
    [point_x, point_y] 
    for point_x, point_y in neighbors 
    if 0 <= point_x < max_x and 0 <= point_y < max_y
]
```

This eliminates modifying iterated collection and marginally reduces code repeat with unpacking. `max_x` and `max_y` are defined before this - you don't need to redeclare them in a loop anyway. I'd also use tuples instead of nested lists, if you don't need mutability.

Comment: Don't use variables `x` and `y`, it looks like those are the iteration variables of the loop that this is part of.

Comment: @Barmar could you please clarify? These `x` and `y` are `x` and `y` coordinates, obtained from the `neighbours` sequence. What's wrong with unpacking a pair of coordinates into `x` and `y`? (they *are* iteration variables indeed)

Comment: Because you're overwriting the variables used by `neighbors=[[x+i,y+j] for i in (-1,0,1) for j in (-1,0,1) if i != 0 or j != 0]`. This code will be in the same scope.

Comment: Just rename your variables so they don't conflict with existing variables.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I didn't notice that "out of question" loop which is never mentioned except these undefined `x` and `y`... Updated!

Answer (score 1):

You could write a helper function that directly produces a list of valid neighbors:

```
def getNeighbors(R,C,rCount,cCount):
    return [ (nR,nC) for nR in (R-1,R,R+1) if nR in range(rCount)
                     for nC in (C-1,C,C+1) if nC in range(cCount)
                     and (nR,nC) != (R,C) ]
```

Output:

```
getNeighbors(11,0,12,10) # [(10, 0), (10, 1), (11, 1)]

# generally speaking:

neighbors = getNeighbors(x,y,max_x+1,max_y+1)
```

This would avoid adding and then removing invalid coordinates when building the neighbors list

If not in a helper function, you could use the same approach to build the neighbors list directly:

```
neighbors = [[nx,ny] for nx in (x-1,x,x+1) if nx in range(max_x+1)
                     for ny in (y-1,y,y+1) if ny in range(max_y+1)
                     and (nx,ny) != (x,y)]
```

Comment: Please avoid using mixedCase for function names - they should be snake_case in order to not violate PEP8.